# Programmatically registering a Sharepoint 2007 event handler

Tags: event-handlers, events

I have an event handler for the ItemAdding event of a document library.  However, I cannot get it to handle the event unless I register the event handler using the Sharepoint Event Handler Manager.  This is fine on a development server, but moving to production, I'd like to be able to register it programatically.  Is there a way to do this without using the Sharepoint Event Handler Manager?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a web-scoped feature with a feature receiver like this:

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
  using (SPWeb web = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb)
  {
    SPList myList = web.Lists["My List"]; 
    if (myList != null)
    {
      string assemblyName = "MyAssembly, [full 4-part name]";
      string className = "MyAssembly.MyItemEventHandler";
      myList.EventReceivers.Add(SPEventReceiverType.ItemAdding, assemblyName, className);
    }
  }
}
```

You should then remove the event receiver when the feature is deactivated.

Comment: Thanks Laurie.  I have to create a whole different feature?  I can't bundle this in with my SPItemEventReceiver feature?

Comment: Yes, a feature receiver is different from an item event receiver. The feature receiver executes when a feature is activated by the user under site actions>site settings>manage site features.

Comment: Ok, so I've created a feature receiver class that inherits from SPFeatureReceiver.  The code assigns the event receiver to my list.  I'm a little confused on how the manifest and feature files are set up.  Please take a look at my latest post if you can provide any insight on this.  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In 2007, you can do this declaratively as well in your content type definition:

```
<XmlDocuments>
        <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/events">
            <spe:Receivers xmlns:spe="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/events">
                <Receiver>
                    <Name>YOURRECEIVERDISPLAYNAME</Name>
                    <Type>ItemUpdating</Type>
                    <SequenceNumber>10001</SequenceNumber>
                    <Assembly>ASSEMBLY, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=YOURTOKEN</Assembly>                                                <Class>RECEIVER CLASS</Class>
                </Receiver>
                <!-- repeat for other events like ITemAdded etc. -->
            </spe:Receivers>
        </XmlDocument>
    </XmlDocuments>
```

P.S: It works in 2010 as well but only for types that have INHERIT set to false

Comment: In the same file as my <Elements>? <Elements><Receivers><Receiver> etc..

Comment: yes, inside the <ContentType tag, under the fieldrefs

Comment: ContentType tag?  You can see what my files look like here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215202/sharepoint-event-handler-not-firing  I'm not sure what you're referring to

Comment: This code would go in your element manifest file for your content type definition. From your question, though I don't see that you have defined a content type for your document library. So, you would either need to define a content type and attach your event receiver declaratively as defined here, or use code (e.g. in a feature receiver) to attach your ItemAdding event receiver to your specific list.

Comment: The content type gets created in the code.

Comment: @Colin - where can I put this code if I dont' define any content types in XML?